# Group meetings MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a database that monitors staff leave and training, every 8 weeks a group will gather and then do training, what i am after is a way to rather than individually assign each member a training event id rather open the event and select the participants, from here each staff member will have this specific training logged against them
So far i have each staff recognised by ID and each training by GID but am having trouble entering this training event in against all IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This **BULK INSERT** could be probably done by using an Unbound Form. The minimal controls would be one Listbox, ComboBox, a TextBox and a Button.

*ListBox* (**staffList**), which should be allowed to select multiple items; will obtain its RowSource from the Staff table, something like

```
SELECT 
    staffID, 
    staffName
FROM 
    staffTable;
```

The properties would be `Bound Column : 1`, `Column Count : 2`, `Column Widths : 0cm;2.542cm`

The *ComboBox* (**eventCombo**), will obtain its RowSource from the Event table, something like

```
SELECT 
    eventID, 
    eventName
FROM 
    eventTable;
```

The properties would be `Bound Column : 1`, `Column Count : 2`, `Column Widths : 0cm;2.542cm`

Then the *TextBox* (**dateTxt**) would just have a Date control (for the date of the event).

The code behind the *Button* (**addEventBtn**) click would simply be,

```
Private Sub addEventBtn_Click()
    Dim varItem As Variant

    If Me.staffList.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "No Staff selected. You have to select at least one staff before you can proceed !", vbCritical
        Me.dateTxt.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.eventCombo.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "No Event selected. You have to select at least one staff before you can proceed !", vbCritical
        Me.dateTxt.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If IsNull(Me.dateTxt) Then
        MsgBox "No Date selected. You have to select Date before you can proceed !", vbCritical
        Me.dateTxt.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each varItem In Me.staffList.ItemsSelected
        CurrentDB.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_EventList (eventID_FK, staffID_FK, eventDate) VALUES (" & _
                          Me.eventCombo & ", " & Me.staffList.ItemData(varItem) & ", " & Format(Me.dateTxt, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & ")"
    Next
End Sub
```

This should work out. Please change it according to your design ! If you have any questions please add them to comments.